# Cucumber - How to test for multiple "Then" conditions within a single Scenario?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In my cucumber test I want to check two conditions at the end of my Scenario, e.g.

```
Scenario: Category product listing page correctly
  Given I am on the product page
  Then I should see "Product Categories"
  And I should see 10 table rows in the products table
```

However when I run the test the "And..." is ignored.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: That should work.  What do mean it's "ignored"?

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber will stop executing the scenario once it sees a failure. Chances are your first 'then' step is failing.

Answer (score 0):

A scenario can have any number of Then statements and steps can be in any order.

I've written tests have multiple Given...When...Then blocks in the same scenario and while it's certainly not best practice, it does work.